# The Problem witch Chosen Jquery and Postback in .net asp

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-chosen, prototype-chosen

i am a problema in use Jquery Chosen in ASP.NET. The item performs a postback and has class="chosen-select". when performing the postback you lose the chosen-select.
I have tried to add this script but it doesn't work:

$(document).ready(function () {Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(PageLoaded)});
function PageLoaded(sender, args) {$("#MainContent_ddlTabla").chosen();}

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjT8n.png

Comment: Could you please share where are you submitting the value and share minimul reproducible code snippet.

Comment: Sure. I have a field of type asp:DropDownList that has an AutoPostBack="True". For my part, I added the chosen so that the field has the characteristics of jquery chosen: class="chosen-select". When executing the program, said field takes the property chosen without problem. But when displaying the asp:DropDownList and selecting a data, it performs the autopostback to bring the data and load another data in cascade. When carrying out this process, it loses the value of the chosen property if I want to choose another data.

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTabla" runat="server" DataTextField="Nombre" DataValueField="Nombre" AppendDataBoundItems="True" class="chosen-select" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTabla_SelectedIndexChanged" ValidationGroup="AgregarVinculo"></asp:DropDownList>